# Trigger asp.net update panel using hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel

I am developing a website in asp.net 2010 and use asp.net controls to use Ajax.
I have an update panel that does not have _Load event and no trigger tag and should be triggered (not updated) manually by clicking a hyperlink (tag 'a'). I have to use hyperlink instead of other controls such as button for some reasons.Now I want a javascript or jquery function to trigger my update panel or call a function in server side code that triggers it.
my asp.net code:

```
<a id="trg" href="#div5"></a>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

my c# function that should be called to update UpdateUanel1 by clicking hyperlink trg:

```
protected void func()
{
    Label1.Text=System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please post some code and explain specifically what is not working and how you'd expect it to work.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use a LinkButton instead of a hyperlink? This is exactly the kind of thing it can be used for.

Comment: yes I only have to use hyperlink. I tried onclick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', ''); in my hyperlink but it is good when we have UpdatePanel1_Load event and good for update it not trigger.